# Why is it a bad idea to have multiple values in a column in a relational database?

Tags: normalization, relational-theory, rdbms

One problem I've found is slow database queries. If I had a table that had a column titled **customer** and another column titled **grocery_items** that contained multiple grocery items, then a simple query to find customers with a particular grocery item would take much longer as it would have to search the entire list of grocery items for every row in the worst case.

I was wondering if that is **the only problem** with not having atomic values in a column. I've looked at videos on Youtube, and they mostly talk about the rules of 1NF and not all of the problems associated with not following those rules.

Comment: If you have a specific issue, then please post the schema, sample data and your query.

Comment: "it would have to search the entire list of grocery items for every row in the worst case" not if your tables are correctly indexed.

Answer (score 1):

> One problem I've found is slow database queries...it would have to search the entire list of grocery items for every row in the worst case.

Yes, that's one drawback, in practice.

In theory and in practice, normalization is a design principle to help ensure data integrity though. The improved performance is just an additional benefit.

For example, in your single table that holds all `Customers`, `GroceryItems`, and their relations, if `GroceryItemABC` was accidentally misspelled as `GroceryItemABD` in some rows, and again misspelled as `GrocerItemABZ` in other rows, it would require a carefully crafted query to ensure all misspelled rows were **accurately** updated, and none were missed. And you run into the performance drawback of having to touch every row to do so too.

With a normalized table, that's a single distinct list of `GroceryItems` with a surrogate key such as an integer field called `GroceryId`, then the `Name` of the `GroceryItem` would only exist in a single row in the `GroceryItems` table and can be easily changed **accurately** and atomically by only needing to update a single row by `GroceryId`.

Answer (score 1):

> a simple query to find customers with a particular grocery item would take much longer as it would have to search the entire list of grocery items for every row **in the worst case**.

Not in the *worst* case.
In [just about] ***every*** case.

Remember that relational databases *first* find a set of rows to work with and *then* do things *with* those rows (pull data out of them, change them, whatever).  So, to find your grocery item, buried somewhere inside those big, long lists, the database has to read *every single row* and peek inside each and every one of them.

So Yes, It's slow.
And there's not a thing you can do to improve it, short of doing the job *properly* and Normalising the data.  Sure, these days there are clever[er] types of Index that work with JSON and the like, but they *still* won't give you kind of performance that Doing the Job Right will.

Worse still, though, is trying to *update* one of those lists.

Say you have an entry like this:

```
,aa,ab,ac,ad, ... ,zx,zy,zz,
```

That's (26*26) = 676 entries, plus the 677 delimiters between and around them (you *do* have leading and trailing delimiters, don't you?).  That weighs in at a whopping 2029 characters ...   and one Heck of a shopping trip! :-)

Now, say, you want to change one of those "sub-entries" from `td` to `tr`.
The database has to change the *entire field*, possibly writing it all into Undo (Oracle), then into one or more Transaction logs and, sometime later, into a data file on disk.  In this example, it's having to do all that with over **2000 characters** for each and every update when it should only *need* to do it with **2 characters**.
This will make updates painfully expensive and *slow*.